# What's wrong with my approach to the surface integral?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

**Problem**: A cone-shaped surface lamina $S$ is given by

$$z = 4 - 2 \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}, \; 0 \leq z \leq 4 $$

At each point on $S$, the density is proportional to the distance between the point and the $z$-axis. Find the mass of the lamina.

**Attempt**: Consider a "small" horizontally-cut cut ring. The circle has radius $r = \frac{4-z}{2}$. Then, the circumference has of the circle is $2\pi r = 2\pi \frac{4-z}{2}$. Also, the density is proportional to $r$, so $\rho = k r = k \frac{4-z}{2}$. Hence, at $z = z_0$, the mass of the ring is:
$$(\rho)\cdot\text{(circumference of circle)} = k (\frac{4-z}{2})^2.$$

Setting up integral yields:
$$\int_{[0,4]} k(\frac{4-z}{2})^2 dz = \frac{32}{3}\pi k.$$

**Solution**:

\begin{align*}
\int_{S} \rho\; dS &= \int_R k \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \sqrt{1+ g_x^2 + g_y^2}dA \\
&= k\int_R \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sqrt{1 + \frac{4x^2}{x^2+y^2} + \frac{4y^2}{x^2+y^2}} dA \\
&= k \int_R \sqrt 5 \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \\
&= \frac{16 \sqrt5 k\pi}{3}.
\end{align*}
by appropriate substitution. I know what the solution is saying, but I just can't figure out what's wrong with my approach. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are integrating the mass, you are assuming that the ring has the width $dz$. However, the ring is slanted. The height of the ring is $dz$ and the width of the ring is  $dz\sqrt{4^2 + 2^2}/4 = dz\sqrt{5}/2$.

[image]